# why String S =new string() not valid in C#

Tags: c#, string, primitive-types, reference-type

In  C# we can write

```
Int a=new int();

char a=new Char();

person p=new person();
```

where person is a Class.
So why can't we write

```
string s =new string();
```

After all string is a reference type. 
Then why it's not possible?

Comment: There are several string constructors, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.string(v=vs.110).aspx. There just isn't a constructor without arguments, because you could just use string.Empty anyway. This is not that uncommon and in the framework and elsewhere you often find classes having only constructors with arguments.

Answer (score 8):

You can not write it because `string` has not Constructor taking 0 parameters. 
Instead you can write something like this:

```
String a = new string(new char[]{});
```

Comment: Why would you do that when you can just set the value to `string.Empty`?

Comment: @Deadzone I have just written how he can get string with constructor

Answer (score 2):

int and char are primitive types. In C#, they are really just aliases for the Int32 and Char classes. These classes have constructors with no parameters. In the case of your Person() class, it also has a constructor with no parameters if your code compiles.  Strings are a bit different. Here is the list of valid String constructors according to MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.string(v=vs.110).aspx

- String(Char*)
- String(Char*, Int32, Int32)
- String(Char, Int32)
- String(Char[])
- String(Char[], Int32, Int32)
- String(SByte*)
- String(SByte*, Int32, Int32)
- String(SByte*, Int32, Int32, Encoding)

Personally, I generally just use something along the following if I want to explicitly initialize a String without going through the process of using a constructor mentioned above:

```
String testStr = String.Empty;
```

Which is really the same as:

```
String testStr = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be pointless to use the constructor to create a new string based on another existing string - that's why there is no constructor overload that allows this. Just do

```
string s = "String in a C#";
```

Comment: useless for Int also but we can do it so then why not in case of string ?

Comment: That is because `int`, `char`, .. are value types (`struct`s) which must have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: @AkhilJain Strings are immutable reference types. There's the ldstr IL instruction which allows pushing a new object reference to a string literal, so basically  strings are "special" reference types. They are immutable. Read more about types

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek but Classes are reference type so if we can do this in Class then why not in String !!

Comment: @AkhilJain You cannot do this wtih classes in general, you can only do this with classes that have a parameterless constructor. Parameterless class constructor is generated by default if no other constructor is specified. `string` class has multiple constructors none of which is parameterless, therefore it cannot be instantiated with parameterless constructor call.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a reference type (for example a class), you can choose what constructors it will have (for value types a parameterless constructor is required, so your choice is limited). If you do not specify any, then a default parameterless constructor is created for you implicitly. The C# designer team decided that it is not worth having a parameterless constructor on the `String` type. That's why you cannot call `new string()`. That's all there is to it.

You can do the same with your custom class.

```
public class C
{
    public C(int i)
    {
    }
}

var c = new C(); // invalid
```